# Error al instalar jupyter en pydroid3 en mi tablet

Tags: python, android

queria acerca de esta serie de errores que me impiden instalar la biblioteca jupyter en pydroid3 dede mi tablet android. Puedo instalar pydroid3 normalmente, algunas bibliotecas que intente descargar pude hacerlo, pero cuando quiero instalar la biblioteca jupyter me sale el siguiente error:

> "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'maturin'".

Al ir al terminal de pydroid y escribir 'pip install maturin', me sale el siguiente error:

> "Could not build wheels for maturin which is required to install
> pyproject.toml-based projects.

Ahora mismo estoy haciendo un curso donde se usa jupyter notebook y me serivria un monton poder usar la biblioteca para seguir con el mismo. Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

El error:

> "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'maturin'"

indica el problema, estas instalando `jupyter`, pero para esto necesitas también instalar [`maturin`](https://www.maturin.rs/tutorial.html), simplemente instala maturin:

```
pip install maturin
```

y posteriormente no deberías tener problemas para instalar `jupyter` (Pydroid 3)

```
pip install jupyter
```

Pero si al tratar de instalar [`maturin`](https://www.maturin.rs/tutorial.html), obtienes el error:

> "Could not build wheels for maturin which is required to install
> pyproject.toml-based projects.

instala la biblioteca de esta forma:

```
python -m pip install maturin
```

Comment: Necesito ayuda, no puedo instalar jupyter notebook en mi celular, ya intente instalar maturin y me sigue apareciendo el error de "could not build wheels for maturin, wich ia requiered to install pyproject.toml-based proje ts"